# Java NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress() takes way too long

Tags: java, jvm

I have a very strange situation...I'm running java like this:

`java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -server -classpath "...jar" -verbose com.class args`

I can see it slows down for 20 seconds after:

`[Loaded java.net.DefaultInterface from jdk\jre\lib\rt.jar]`

and before: `[Loaded java.net.NetworkInterface$1 from jdk\jre\lib\rt.jar]`

What could be the problem? Thanks for help in advance

edit:

on verbose:jni I can see it stops on:

`[Dynamic-linking native method java.net.NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress0 ... JNI]`

So I executed following program:

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

class HelloWorldApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    InetAddress ip;
    try {
        ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        System.out.println("Current IP address : " + ip.getHostAddress());
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        NetworkInterface network = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(ip);
        byte[] mac = network.getHardwareAddress();
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        long duration = (endTime - startTime);
        double seconds = (double)duration / 1000000000.0;
        System.out.println("Duration: " +String.valueOf(seconds) + " seconds");
        System.out.print("Current MAC address : ");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : ""));        
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {          
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SocketException e){
            e.printStackTrace();        
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
Current IP address : 192.168.148.38
Duration: 20.188660558 seconds
Current MAC address : 28-B2-BD-46-20-67
```

`NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(ip)` takes about 20 seconds. Any ideas?

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)

javac -version
javac 1.7.0_79
```

Comment: Is this case for *all* Java applications on this machine? Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Probably something is not properly configured on my machine, but I tried to do the same in python and no performance issues there. I have this issue only with java.

Comment: Takes 30ms for me on windows and java8. Afaik performance of networkinterface methods also depends on the number of network interfaces and addresses assigned to the interfaces.